# Plugin for Reading Documents, PDF's etc

Tags: plugins

I am working on a project like scribd.com using WordPress, is there any plugin available which can read documents into a flash or in an Iframe.

Examples:
scribd.com
docstoc.com
books.google.com

Answer (score 0):

Yes this plugin will do that for you: 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tgn-embed-everything/


It will embed your PDF into your site without flash so it can be viewed on any device.